# Парсер json с декодированием текста

Tags: c#

В Json встречаются такие тексты `\u0432\u043b\u0435`, есть ли какой нибудь online парсер Json, который бы декодировал такой текст ?

Comment: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут вроде каждый текст нужно вставлять, а именно Json парсера с декодированием нет ?

Comment: в C# `Json.Decode(...)` из  System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode  не робит чтоль уже?

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо ! Последнее то что нужно, очень удобно.